# Why does std::map not have an insert function of type insert(key &k, val &v)

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Why does `std::map` not support an insert like the following:

```
std::map<obj1, obj2> map_int;

void insert_map(obj1 &key, obj2 &val)
{
    map_int.insert(key, val);
}
```

I know that the above is incorrect. I want to know what prevents from designing the insert function like that. It is more intuitive than creating a pair IMO.

Comment: Isn't this what `map[key] = val` does?

Comment: FWIW, with C++11, you should be able to use `map.intsert({key, val});`.

Comment: @Barmar, that will replace the value if there is an item with the given key. `insert` will not replace the value if there is an item with the given key.

Comment: @Barmar That also involves default-constructing a value - which may be either undesirable or impossible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called [`emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

> ```
> std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
>
> // uses pair's template constructor
> m.emplace("d", "ddd");
> ```

Comment: Again why is pair required? Why can't it simply be insert(key, val)?

Comment: @mc_87 `emplace(key, value)` is doing what you're asking, the only difference being the name of the function.

Comment: @0xhacker, Probably for consistency with all of the other STL containers taking a `value_type` to insert. Generic code benefits from this consistency. However, there could have been benefit in an additional overload for this if the use case had been great enough.

Comment: No, I am more interested in knowing why is a pair constructor required to insert in a stl map? I would assume there is a deeper reason why the simpler interface is not exposed. There must be some problem of inserting the key and value, that using a pair must be solving. I want to know the problem. It will be sad to know that it is complicated for no reason.

Comment: @0xhacker because under the hood, the `value_type` of a `std::map` is `std::pair<first_type, second_type>`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++17, you can use:

```
map_int.try_emplace(key, val);
```

This actually returns some useful information:

```
std::pair<std::map<obj1, obj2>::iterator, bool> p = map_int.try_emplace(key, val);
```

- `p.first` is an iterator that points to the element with the given key.
- `p.second` indicates whether the insertion took place.

You can achieve a similar effect in C++11 with `map_int.emplace(key, val)`, but there are some subtle differences (related to copying/moving of values). Moreover, `try_emplace` allows for convenient construction of arbitrary elements:

```
struct X { X(int, char, bool); };

std::map<int, X> m;
m.try_emplace(10, 20, 'x', false);  // constructs X(20, 'x', false) if new
```

A similar operation in C++11 would look like this:

```
m.emplace(
    std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple(10),
    std::forward_as_tuple(20, 'x', false));
```

Comment: And by the way, C++17 also has `std::map::insert_or_assign` if what you really want to do is overwrite an old value if the key exists, or insert the pair if not.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` *does* have an [`insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) method (several, in fact), it just has a different signature than what you are expecting.  You need to pass it a `std::pair` containing the desired key and value, eg:

```
std::map<obj1, obj2> map_int;

void insert_map(obj1 &key, obj2 &val)
{
    map_int.insert(std::make_pair(key, val));
}
```

Comment: I know this works. In the question I explicitly say that inserting just the key and val is more intuitive than creating a pair. My question was why did the designers/implementors of stl map not have a simpler interface. Why is there a need to complicate it with pair?

Comment: I believe the other comments already cover that. `std::map` is a container of `std::pair` values, and like other containers, you have to insert new values into it using its `value_type`, which in this case is a `std::pair`. If you want to know WHY the standard does not define a simpler interface, ask the C++ committee who designed the interface.